# Issue performing foldchange calculation on large R data set

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I am struggling to find an efficient way to write code that will allow me to look at fold change difference between two groups for various genes.

An example of the data set I am looking at is as follows

[image: Example Data]

The goal is to see the expression fold change between the WT and Mut groups in column Mut for each item in column Gene.

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could do this simply by `group_by` Gene and Mut, then `summarize` to get the mean expression, then `pivot_wider` Mut into 2 columns for WT and Mut, then `mutate` to divide one by the other. But if you're actually working with gene expression data, I'd suggest you use an tool designed for that purpose, like `edgeR`, `limma`, or `DESeq2`.

Comment: @divibisan Thank you for the help, I believe based on your response I have written most of what should work, but the last mutate is confusing me. 

How do I designate that I want the expression of one group to be divided by the expression of the other group?

Minus the last mutate I believe this is what you are describing the code should look like? 

`df %>% group_by(Mut, Gene) %>%
  summarize() %>% pivot_wider(Mut) %>% 
  mutate(Fold = ) `

Unfortunately the data set I was given to work with is not in raw count format so running it through those programs appears to be problematic.

Comment: What are these expression values? Since they're both positive and negative, they look like they're already fold changes

Comment: Sorry those values were from another data set, I have updated the OP with an image of the data I am working with which was described as "mRNA Expression, RSEM (Batch normalized from Illumina HiSeq_RNASeqV2)"

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually working with gene expression data, I'd **strongly** suggest you use a tool designed for that purpose, like `edgeR`, `limma`, or `DESeq2`. Since your expression data is normalized (RPKM or TPM, it looks like) then you can't use `DESeq2`, but edgeR or limma are options.

If you want to do this manually, though, it's a pretty simple tidyverse operation:

```
df <- data.frame(
    gene = rep.int(c('KRAS','CERK','PLPP3'), 6),
    expression = runif(18, 0, 25),
    Mut = c(rep.int('Mut', 9), rep.int('WT', 9))
)

library(tidyverse)
```

First you want to average expression for each gene/mutation group. You do this by grouping the data.frame then summarize the expression values:

```
df2 <- df %>%
    group_by(gene, Mut) %>%
    summarize(expression = mean(expression))

df2
#   gene  Mut   expression
#   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 CERK  Mut         17.0
# 2 CERK  WT          10.4
# 3 KRAS  Mut         11.9
# 4 KRAS  WT          14.0
# 5 PLPP3 Mut         13.0
# 6 PLPP3 WT          17.5
```

Then you want to divide the expression value for mutants by wild-type for each gene. The simplest way to do this is pivot to wide form and use mutate to create a new fold change value:

```
df3 <- df2 %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = 'Mut', values_from = 'expression')
df3

#   gene    Mut    WT
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 CERK   17.0  10.4
# 2 KRAS   11.9  14.0
# 3 PLPP3  13.0  17.5

df3 %>%
    mutate(foldChange = Mut/WT)

#   gene    Mut    WT foldChange
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 CERK   17.0  10.4      1.63 
# 2 KRAS   11.9  14.0      0.850
# 3 PLPP3  13.0  17.5      0.739
```